# Does ES6 solve the performance problems that bundling solves?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Does ES6 import loading load similar to the way AMD loads?  That is, when file1 depends on file2 and file3, does file1 have to load before file2 and file3 start loading?  Or is there a clever mechanism for avoiding the need to bundle file1, file2 and file3?

Comment: You should provide additional information to your post, isn't clear at all... 
(import/export work different to amd)

Answer (score 2):

ES6 does not specify how loading modules should work at all. ES6 only specifies a statically analysable syntax to declare dependencies between modules.

There are loaders that load them in an AMD-like fashion, and there are other loaders that bundle chunks of modules together.

Comment: I was asking about implementations, so I guess the question is targeted to Edge developers only?

Comment: All the current implementations of ES6 modules work alongside existing bundlers, so it's not really a question of one or the other.

Comment: So with respect to this suggestion from/for Edge, https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6510097-es6-modules, are you saying that a bundler will still be needed? So what falls away is the need for a loader but not a bundler?

Comment: @CoreyAlix: I have no idea what Edge is implementing there. The `System.Loader` draft, `<script type="module">` stuff? Do you have any details?

Comment: "Language-level support for defining and consuming modules."
http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html

I'm hoping to get an understanding of what it means.

Comment: That's very vague. It could mean anything from parsing infrastructure in the js engine to [the `Loader` object](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/) to support in HTML. Maybe you should ask for clarification in that thread you linked above.